# Sitecore FeedRenderer Issue when overriding RenderItem()!

Tags: .net, rss, sitecore, sitecore6

Hope you guys can help me.

I'm trying to override the RenderItem() method in FeedRenderer like so:

```
public class RendererTest : Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FeedRenderer
{

    public override System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationItem RenderItem()
    {
        return base.RenderItem();
    }
}
```

this basic implementation is generating a compiling error that states that: `return type must be 'System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationItem' to match overridden member 'Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FeedRenderer.RenderItem()'`

I'm returning the value from base, how can it not match the override

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that in .NET 4 this class was moved from the assembly System.ServiceModel.Web to System.ServiceModel. Try including both assemblies in your references -- this allowed me to successfully compile the code you include above.